# Modbus TCP in Java / Android

Tags: java, tcp, modbus

I am working on a modbus TCP implementation in Java. I've tried 3 different libraries so far modbus4j, jamod, and j2mod. I can successfully access my slave device with the linux modpoll tool: http://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html

```
michael@michael-G75VW:~/Documents/modbus-test-tool/linux$ ./modpoll -a255 -r1 -1        192.168.1.101
modpoll 3.4 - FieldTalk(tm) Modbus(R) Master Simulator
Copyright (c) 2002-2013 proconX Pty Ltd
Visit http://www.modbusdriver.com for Modbus libraries and tools.

Protocol configuration: MODBUS/TCP
Slave configuration...: address = 255, start reference = 1, count = 1
Communication.........: 192.168.1.101, port 502, t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table

-- Polling slave...
[1]: 256
```

This causes the barrier on my device to go up which is great. However, working in the Java implementation I am unable to reproduce this. I've tried many different steps but all fail. In J2mod/jamod I continually get a invalid slaveId error when using '255' which is the unit id i use in the above command. If I use anything else, I get a CRC failed error. In mod4j I get various errors including error code = 4. Here is my latest J2mod code which returns either CRC error (if not 255) or invalid slaveId. I know slaveId is mostly used for Serial communications, but my device only responds to a Unit ID of 255 when using other applications.

```
Integer value = Integer.decode(val).intValue();
    Integer unitID = Integer.decode(uid).intValue();
    Integer length = Integer.decode(len).intValue();
    Integer ref = Integer.decode(reference).intValue();
    SimpleRegister MyReg = new SimpleRegister(value);
    try {
        InetAddress address;
        address = InetAddress.getByName(addr);
        //2. Open the connection
        TCPMasterConnection con = new TCPMasterConnection(address);
        con.setPort(port);
        con.connect();
        //3. Prepare the requestWrite
        WriteSingleRegisterRequest WriteReq = new WriteSingleRegisterRequest(ref,MyReg);
        WriteReq.setDataLength(length);
        WriteReq.setUnitID(unitID);
        //4. Prepare the transaction
        ModbusTCPTransaction trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(WriteReq);  
        trans.setRetries(0);
        trans.execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "Complete: " +trans.toString());
        return trans.getResponse().getHexMessage();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Exception: " + e.toString());
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

My manual for the modbus interface is available here:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ac-magnetic.com%2Fgermany%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2F58150001EN_00_Technical%2520Maunal%2520EM01.pdf&ei=Z1dxUv7qF4a9yAGpooHYBQ&usg=AFQjCNGGZnBx_A0fFjuW3qqgWjhS_ek-0w&bvm=bv.55617003,d.aWc

Comment: Isn't ID 255 usually a broadcast ID?  Can you try readdressing the slave to something else, like 1?  In practice, I never see anyone using 255 as a Modbus slave address.  Don't know if that will help, but there may be something in your libraries won't like '255'.

Comment: No, unit 0 is the broadcast address, except with Modbus/TCP PLCs, which typically use unit 0 for all communications.  The only (general ...) exception is when the PLC is attached through a bridge and the bridge marshals the PDUs between the TCP/IP connection side and some other transport side.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to why, exactly, this is happening.  I can tell you that both jamod and j2mod (j2mod is a bug-fixed fork of jamod) simply copy whatever you set as the unit number to the 7th byte of the TCP packet.  It's then up to the PLC to respond to the packet, as sent.

For j2mod, setting the system property `com.ghgande.modbus.debug` equal to "true" from the JVM command line will enable debug messages. That will allow you to view a packet dump that should tell you what's happening.

You do make one very interesting comment, and that is that you are seeing CRC errors.  You are aware that Modbus/TCP doesn't use a CRC at all?